# User space swap

Tags: process, virtual-machine, disk, swap, out-of-memory

I have low physical memory `1GB` in my VPS container based (LXC), therefore I can't change kernel parameter such as swap memory swappiness. Even though there is swap allocated from built-in VPS when I checked with `htop`, I don't know why OOM killer still killing `myprogram.py` and seems didn't utilize the swap when memory is 100% being used.

I tried `swapon /swapfile` what I got was `Operation not permitted` even though I was root. I do realize when inside guest container I don't have permission to modify any kernel parameter.

Therefore, I expect I can do command like this:

```
disk-as-ram run "python3 myprogram.py" --allocate 4GB --filename "myvirtualmemory.mem"
```

So, it will running an isolated process called `python3 myprogram.py`, what my program see will be a system that has `4GB` RAM (memory), which actually allocating 4GB disk for R/W operation that actually I/O operation. The allocated 4GB will be stored in filename called `myvirtualmemory.mem`

So, is there command like that? Maybe `chroot` environment can help me.